# What am I doing wrong, it seems all my codes are right but I'm I'm getting an error 404 on my add to cart Django e-commerce app

Tags: python, django

My server is starting correctly but I keep getting a page not found error.

```
from django.urls import path
from .Views import Home
from cart views import Home, add_to_cart, remove_from_cart

app_name= 'mainapp' 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='cart'), 
    path('cart/<slug>', add_to_cart, name='cart'),
    path('remove/<slug>', remove_from_cart, name='remove-cart'), 
]
```

This is the code in my products/urls.py

Comment: two urls have same name, change to different one, name='cart'

Comment: Can you show the url you are typing in browser.

Comment: Please which of the url have the same name?

Comment: @sandeep ...... 127.0.0.1:8000/cart/

Comment: This "127.0.0.1:8000/cart/" does not match any of your url. Please check, you have three urls, a blank (""), cart/<slug> and remove/<slug>. 2) Nmae for 1st two urls are same.

Answer (score 0):

Provide different name to the url and add trailing slash also.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='home'), 
    path('cart/<slug>/', add_to_cart, name='cart'),
    path('remove/<slug>/', remove_from_cart, name='remove-cart'), 
]
```

Comment: please note, you have added cart two times and also there was no trailing slash after the slug